# Узнать минимальный размер "параллелепипеда", в который поместить модель three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

Загружаю произвольную модель с помощью jsonLoader
Нужно узнать высоту, длину и ширину этой модель. Что то на подобии выделенной белыми линиями модели в ее углах в 3D максе.
Или другими словами, найти минимальные размеры параллелепипеда, в который она поместится

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Покопавшись немного в логах, нашел такую строчку: `BoundingBox`, но она оказалась `null`, немного погуглив, нашел метод:

```
computeBoundingBox();
```